# html5 search input does not work with bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have tested the `input[type="search"]` and it does not show the clear `(x)` icon when the bootstrap styles have been applied.

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. What bootstrap styles are you "adding"? Default search input box styling is provided by the browser, as long as it's not < IE9. Then it will be a default text box.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MbDgj/3/

Comment: Paystey, it works, but when i add the bootstrap styles it stop. See the fiddle link that i add

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An issue related to yours has been already posted in their [github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/5624)

Answer (score 56):

```
input[type="search"] {
 -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
 box-sizing: content-box;
 -webkit-appearance: searchfield;
}

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
-webkit-appearance: searchfield-cancel-button;
}
```

works for me on Chrome (on my Mac, but not on my iPhone...)

Comment: Actually, for the cancel button specifically, I think you only need this bit:

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
-webkit-appearance: searchfield-cancel-button;
}

Comment: @Giolvani Please do everyone a solid and mark this the right answer! Thanks Thierry

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Web Kit your problem may be related to what sk8terboi87 posted.

Bootstrap doesn't support styling the `Search` type inputs for you as it's too difficult to do reliably in Web Kit.

Bootstrap uses a reset CSS which removes the cross that usually appears, you can get it back by modifying the core CSS, but this could cause issues in the future when upgrading.

If it's happening in other browsers though it could be another issue.

Answer (score 1):

To have the same user experience across all devices, I ended up writing an Angular directive that I put on Bootstrap 'input-group-btn's.

Angular view HTML

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="search" id="listItemSearch" class="form-control"
        placeholder="Search text..." 
        title="Search" aria-label="Search"
        data-ng-model-options="{'debounce':1500, 'updateOn':'blur default'}"
        data-ng-model="vm.filters.listItemSearchText"/>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
            data-ng-disabled="!vm.filters.listItemSearchText" 
            aria-describedby="listItemSearch" 
            data-clear-search-by-aria="#listItemSearch">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
    </span>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span>{{vm.models.listSearchResults.length}}</span>
        <span>/</span>
        <span>{{vm.data.list.length}}</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Angular directive JavaScript

```
.directive( 'clearSearchByAria', ['$parse', function clearSearchByAria( $parse )
{
    return(
    {
        'restrict':'A',
        'link':function clearSearchByAria_link( scope, jqElem, ngAttr )
        {
            jqElem.on( 'click', function( $event )
            {
                var $clickedElem = angular.element($event.currentTarget);
                var $searchInput;

                // Specified by selector.
                if( !!ngAttr.clearSearchByAria )
                {
                    var $specifiedElem = angular.element(ngAttr.clearSearchByAria)
                    if( $specifiedElem.length == 1 )
                    {$searchInput = $specifiedElem;}
                }
                else
                {
                    var $describedElem = $clickedElem.find( '[aria-describedby]' ).addBack( '[aria-describedby]' );
                    // Specified by 'aria-describedby'.
                    if( $describedElem.length == 1 )
                    {$searchInput = angular.element(''.concat( '#', $describedElem.attr('aria-describedby')));}
                    else
                    {
                        throw( new ReferenceError( "'clear-search-by-aria' attributes requires either 1) to be empty and for the element (or a descendant) to have an 'aria-describedby' attribute referring to another element or 2) to specify an element selector (e.g. '#id') to another element." ));
                    }
                }

                if( !!$searchInput && $searchInput.length == 1 )
                {
                    var ng_model = $searchInput.data( 'ngModel' ) || $searchInput.attr( 'ng-model' );
                    if( !!ng_model )
                    {
                        var modelGetter = $parse( ng_model );
                        modelGetter.assign( scope, '' );
                        scope.$apply();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $searchInput.val( '' );
                    }
                }
            });
        },
    });
}])`
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your input type to 'search'instead of 'text' and -webkit-appearance: block instead of 'none'

Comment: Doesn't work with Firefox (tested with v115.0)