# Input text field with close button

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i just want to make an input text field with a little x (close) button at the top right corner. please help me out how it should be done in css3 or bootstrap 3. Thank you

Comment: what is the close button for? Clear input value?

Comment: Or do you mean a simple modal that you can close?

Comment: It was in Stackoverflow [before][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20062218/how-do-i-clear-a-search-box-with-an-x-in-bootstrap-3

Comment: i need the same field here you can see it on the left side of page https://www.desmos.com/calculator

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ap6tx0j6/):

html:

```
<input type="text"><span class="close-icon">x</span>
```

css:

```
    .close-icon{
       position:relative;
       left: -14px;
       top: -4px;
    }
```

Comment: thank for your support can you make the same input field for me please ?? here is the link https://www.desmos.com/calculator

Answer (score 0):

[Check this](https://jsfiddle.net/bk72q5wg/)

HTML

```
<div class="main-content">
     <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="close">X</a>
   Dummy Text will be here..  Dummy Text will be here.. 
</div>
```

css

```
.main-content{
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    height:200px;
    width:50%;
    position:relative;
    padding:10px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size:12px;
}
.close{
    position: absolute;
    right:5px;
    top:5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: arial;
    color:#fff;
    background-color: #aaa;
    padding:3px 5px
}
```

Comment: thank for your support can you make the same input field for me please ?? here is the link https://www.desmos.com/calculator