# How to make icon on top of input field responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am having an issue with making my icon staying fixed on the top right corner of the input field to be responsive. I want to be able to make it adjust to various screen sizes. I currently have the following codes:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <form class="form-class">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>
        <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span>Username</span>
      </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    </form>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    .form-class input {
        width: 70vw;
        @media all and (min-width: 768px) {
          width: 30vw;
        }
        @media all and (min-width: 1200px) {
          width: 25vw;
        }
    }

    .form-class label {
        position: relative;
        font-size: 2rem;
        @media all and (min-width: 768px) {
          font-size: 3rem;
        }

    }

   .form-class label .fa-exclamation-circle  {
              position: absolute;
              font-size: 0.7em;
              color: red;
              top: 28px;
              left: 427px;
              @media all and (min-width: 375px) {
                left: 255px;
              }
              @media all and (min-width: 768px) {
                top: 35px;
                left: 295px;
              }
              @media all and (min-width: 1440px) {
                top: 35px;
                left: 350px;
              }
}
```

The above method doesn't work very well because I am only targeting very specific screen sizes. Is using absolute positioning the right approach here or is there a better way of doing this? How would I make the exclamation icon be responsive across all screen sizes?

A live demo can be found here: https://jsbin.com/kixiliduju/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Do you want it inside, or outside?

Comment: @banzomaikaka I want half of it in and half of it outside like in the demo.

Comment: does this work? http://jsbin.com/tujihisare/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You mean add something look like the clear button on searchbox? So you can try this [How do I clear a search box with an 'x' in bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20062218/how-do-i-clear-a-search-box-with-an-x-in-bootstrap-3)

Answer (score 0):

Why not build upon the existing `.has-feedback` styles already in Bootstrap?

```css
.form-group {
  /* define width of input field / label;
     override for other resolutions as necessary */
  width: 70vw;
}

/* define form-group label font size */
.form-group > label {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

/* override default .form-control-feedback colour;
   NB: radial-gradient ensures middle of icon will always show as white,
       otherwise it's possible to see part of the input field through
       the icon */
.has-feedback label ~ .form-control-feedback::before {
  color: red;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse 40% 40% at 50% 50%, #fff 0%, #fff 99%, transparent 100%)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <form class="form-class">

    <div class="form-group has-error has-feedback">
      <label class="control-label" for="name">Username</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Username" id="name" aria-describedby="name_status">
      <span class="fa fa-exclamation-circle form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span id="name_status" class="sr-only">(error)</span>
    </div>

  </form>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add below css and add a class in `<i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle rightSide" aria-hidden="true"></i>` in html part (**"class name - rightSide"**) which i added in your markup.

```
.form-group {
  position:relative;
}
.rightSide {
  position:absolute;
  right:10px;
  top:20px;
  color:red;
}
```

Remove `form-class` form HTML part.

```
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>
        <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle rightSide" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span>Username</span>
      </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
  </form>
```

Here is working fiddle

**[fiddle update](https://jsfiddle.net/0zvfvm6q/1/)**