# conflicting bootstrap and input type search

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, search

I have following input:

```
<input class="search" type="search" data-column="all">
```

by default it renders like this(`x` renders):

[image]

When I add bootstrap bootstrap.min.css `x` doesn't shows

My page depends on bootstrap thus I cannot remove it.
Please, help to fix my issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [html5 search input does not work with bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13956868/html5-search-input-does-not-work-with-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type="search"] {
 -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
 box-sizing: content-box;
 -webkit-appearance: searchfield;
}

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
-webkit-appearance: searchfield-cancel-button;
}
```

taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/18813579/2674303