# Angular 2 - Clear text field with button inside input field

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I want to clear ngModel after clicking on **x** button.

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback marginBottom10">
    <input type="text" id="searchInput" [(ngModel)]="searchClass" (keyup.enter)="searchSchemaClass(searchClass)" 
      class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="{{ 'App.Labels.Search' | translate}}" />  
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" *ngIf="searchClass" (click)="searchClass=''"></span>
</div>
```

Don't understand why its not clearing textbox. Even i tried to invoke function on click, but its not working.

Comment: Using Bootstrap...

Answer (score 0):

You can use input `type="search"`

```
<input type="search" id="searchInput" 
 [(ngModel)]="searchClass" 
 (keyup.enter)="searchSchemaClass(searchClass)" 
 class="form-control" name="search" 
 placeholder="{{ 'App.Labels.Search' | translate}}" />
```

> **Note**: It has support for IE11+ and other modern browser, [check here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-search)

---

Custom version

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback marginBottom10">
    <input type="text" id="searchInput" [(ngModel)]="searchClass" (keyup.enter)="searchSchemaClass(searchClass)" 
      class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="{{ 'App.Labels.Search' | translate}}" />  
      <span
        class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" 
        *ngIf="searchClass?.length" (click)="searchClass=''">
      </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried both, But hard luck :/

Comment: Thanks for ans ! Seems like there was prob with Bootstrap --> This solution helped me https://stackoverflow.com/a/18813579/5407008

Answer (score 0):

Change your input `type="text"` in input `type=search`, transform your click function in `(click)="clear()"` and in your ts do:

```
clear(){
  this.searchClass = null;
}
```

This should work.