# Click not working for input type "text" in iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, asp.net-mvc-4

I wanted to implement a clear button for my textbox. I found a really nice solution in the SO thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258521/clear-icon-inside-input-text). 
I'll paste the js code here:

```
function tog(v){return v?'addClass':'removeClass';} 

$(document).on('input', '.clearable', function(){
    $(this)[tog(this.value)]('x');
}).on('mousemove', '.x', function( e ){
    $(this)[tog(this.offsetWidth-18 < e.clientX-this.getBoundingClientRect().left)]('onX');   
}).on('click', '.onX', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('x onX').val('');
});
```

I implemented this on my site and it works perfectly on the desktop. However, when I tested the same in iPad, it didn't work at all.
I tried to replace the "click" with "tochstart"/"touch" but it doesn't makes any change.

I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sourabh_Singh_Rathore/D2ACE/1/) of the code so you can see. Please help me out, How do I resolve this so it works for both desktop and iPad.

Comment: how did you used the touchstart??

Comment: like this: `.on('touchstart', '.onX', function(){ $(this).removeClass('x onX').val(''); });`

Answer (score 0):

You could try to combine "click" and "touchstart", like this: http://jsfiddle.net/veritas87/D2ACE/2/

```
.on('touchstart click', '.onX', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('x onX').val('');
});
```

You can also try the "tap" event, described here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/event_tap.asp

Comment: I tried your fiddle in my iPad(mini), but it's not working..!!

Comment: Yeah, I tried tap, it works in the emulation but not in the device itself.
Do you think the problem might be that I am trying to attach a click event to a textbox??