# X button in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to do something like this with my field

[image]

I've tried:

```
<input type="image" class="button" src="search-button.png" title="Search..." />
```

And:

```
#search .button { float:right; margin:7px 7px 0 0; }
```

But I couldn't get the image to go *inside*, the field. So my question is how can I accomplish this? I've tried putting them both in a `div`, and `form`, also but that didn't work. I've also tried using a pseudo element. But still couldn't get it to go in.

Comment: use absolute position so you can put image over top

Comment: Like [this](http://jsbin.com/qayubaka/1/edit)? Also how can I prevent the repeat @charlietfl

Comment: i was assuming you were using another element...read up on how to use background posiiton and no-repeat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following structure you can achieve it.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="Test"><input type="text" class="hex" maxlength="6">
<div class="newclass"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.nwea.org/warmup/sample_tests/_resources/img/css/closeX.png" /></a></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .hex {
width: 406px;
height: 40px;
font-size: 1.875em;
outline: none;
background: none;
border: 3px solid black;
vertical-align: middle;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding-left: 5px;
transition: 1s;
}
.Test
{
position:relative;
width:406px;
}
.newclass
 {
height:20px;
position:absolute;
top:12px;
right:0px;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5XhUg/2/)

Comment: How would OP be able to click on the X? And clear the field. I think that would be a bonus.

Comment: Answer Updated Idris.

Comment: Can you tell me why it doesn't work when I try using the `#`, before. http://jsbin.com/gomejazi/1

Comment: you need to write the class for that.

Comment: add position:absolute property to that .hash class.

Comment: you missed semicolan(;) after the style absolute.

Answer (score -1):

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jats_ptl/FynJm/)

```
.search-box,.close-icon,.search-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}
.search-wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.search-box {
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  outline: 0;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.search-box:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 5px #b0e0ee;
  border: 2px solid #bebede;
}
.close-icon {
  border:1px solid transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
   outline: 0;
   cursor: pointer;
}
.close-icon:after {
  content: "X";
  display: block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FA9595;
  z-index:1;
  right: 35px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #E50F0F;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

For Image:
Please Refer: [Clear icon inside input text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258521/clear-icon-inside-input-text)

Comment: How can I do an image instead though?

Comment: The problem with all of those is I'm using `background: none;`, to get the clear effect. How would I go about it now?

Comment: Will you please create a fiddle for that.. so it would be easier to have a look..

Comment: if background: none; is used then How you are going to show image.

Comment: Another issue is that if this is used on a form with any other fields, the entire form will be reset.

Comment: Well I needed it to be transparent. Any ideas on how I'd do it?

Comment: I'd say it was downvoted because it didn't answer OPs question completely.

Comment: oh I see...OP is up-voting it as soon as I upload the answer and latter on other members down-vote that... it doesn't matter to me but please down-vote with precise reasons.