# jQuery not working if input field is prefilled (toggle clear function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, onload

I've found a jQuery script here at *[Clear icon inside input text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258521/clear-icon-inside-input-text)* which brings a clear-icon inside an input field. It fits perfect in my website. But it's not working, when the input value is prefilled.

*[Demo at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/sejuquta/1/edit)*

I tried several `onchange()`, `change()` in additon to `mousemove` and also replaced in the script itself and the following in html:

```
<body onLoad="tog(v);">
```

**JS**

```
function tog(v){return v?'addClass':'removeClass';} 

$(document).on('input', '.clearable', function(){
    $(this)[tog(this.value)]('x');
}).on('mousemove', '.x', function( e ){
    $(this)[tog(this.offsetWidth-18 < e.clientX-this.getBoundingClientRect().left)]('onX');   
}).on('click', '.onX', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('x onX').val('');
});
```

But it did'nt help. Do you have any solution?

Comment: In the demo, it isn't pre-filled correct?

Comment: That's correct. But it let's easily type in something in the value attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to trigger `input` event programmatically using [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
  $('.clearable').trigger('input');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/sejuquta/480/edit)

Comment: Wow Satpal, thanks a lot for your fast and working solution! You made my day ;-)