# No clear button in Firefox for input type search?

Tags: css, html, firefox

```
<input type="search" />
input[type="search"]
{
   -webkit-appearance: searchfield
}
```

makes the clear(x) button appear when you type something in the input, but how do you make the same thing happen in Firefox?

Thanks!

Comment: Javascript solution to this can be found here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258521/clear-icon-inside-input-text

Answer (score 14):

Firefox has been dragging their feet on this [for years and years](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=558594).  Contrary to the other answer, there is still (as of late 2017) no native way of including a clear button on an input.  You can of course insert your own and style it manually, in which case you'd do well to use

```
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button { display: none }
```

to avoid having the native clear button show up on browsers that support it.