# Firefox has no "x" to remove content on input type="search"

Tags: html

When adding a  a "x" is added in IE, chrome and safari when you start typing as a functional UI control for clearing the input. However on FF there is no such option.

It is a valid W3C input type as you can [see here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp).

Is there a way to add it just for FF or should you just remove them on other browsers and create it using JS instead?

Comment: You could manually add the "x".. see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258521/clear-icon-inside-input-text/33683886#33683886) for several options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258521/clear-icon-inside-input-text/33683886#33683886

Comment: You should leave it as is as it is a browser thing. This has nothing to do with making a website and all the users who has Firefox are aware of this.