# Form input type time clear event in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, input, time

When I click the little "X" in an input form field of type "time" I want to fire an event.

I tried the click event but it does not work. It seems like the "X" is an element above the input field. It triggers when clicking inside it somewhere else.

[image]

```
$( "input" ).click(function() {
  console.log( "Clear has been clicked" );
});
```

How can I fire an event on input "X" (clear)?

Comment: Please show html of "X"

Comment: **[`Hope this helps`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258521/clear-icon-inside-input-text)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `input` event:

```
$( "input" ).on('input', function() {
  console.log( "Clear has been clicked" );
});
```