# updating dataTable search

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I use the [dataTables](https://datatables.net/) plugin on my website and I am having some minor problems with my search bar, which is included in said plugin;
I am using that code to clear the search bar emptying the input field:

```
    function tog(v){return v?'addClass':'removeClass';} 
$(document).on('input', '.clearable', function(){
    $(this)[tog(this.value)]('x');
}).on('mousemove', '.x', function( e ){
    $(this)[tog(this.offsetWidth-18 < e.clientX-this.getBoundingClientRect().left)]('onX');
}).on('touchstart click', '.onX', function( ev ){
    ev.preventDefault();
    $(this).removeClass('x onX').val('').change().submit();
 });
```

which is taken from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6258628/5869867)

Now to the problem: whenever I click on the cross that I asigned for the clearing of the input, said input gets cleared like it should, however, the dataTable table keeps displaying only table rows, which correspond to the search input. How can I clear the dataTable search when clicking the cross. I noticed that it only takes the pressing of a key like backspace, arrow down, ... to update the search.

Comment: After clearing input field, just call `oTable.fnDraw()` ..

Comment: `oTable` is object of your DataTable..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two options

1. tell `dataTable` that search field has been changed by triggering `keyup` event

   ```
   // on 'touchstart click' event
   $(this).keyup();
   ```
2. `reDraw` table manually

   ```
   var table = $('#example').DataTable();
   table.search('').draw();
   ```