# I am trying to create a nested element, using a reduced CKEditor textfield-dialog, but it wont work

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

i am using the CKEditor to enable writing on a page in my project. In this area where the CKEditor writes, there should also be the possibilty to insert a textfield, im using the standard textfield-dialog plugin ([the 4th button in the 2nd row](http://ckeditor.com/demo#full)) with only the value field. By using the config.js:

```
var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'info' );
    // remove unwanted input fields
    infoTab.remove( '_cke_saved_name' );
    infoTab.remove( 'size' );
    infoTab.remove( 'maxLength' );
    infoTab.remove( 'type' );
```

And i wanted to modify the onOk-function of the used value-field by inserting a nested element containing the textfield.

Original:

```
onOk: function() {
        var a = this.getParentEditor(),
            c = this.textField,
            b = !c;
        b && (c = a.document.createElement("input"), c.setAttribute("type", "text"));
        c = {
            element: c
        };
        b && a.insertElement(c.element);
        this.commitContent(c);
        b || a.getSelection().selectElement(c.element)
    }
```

Modified:

```
    onOk: function() {
        var a = this.getParentEditor(),
            c = this.textField,
            b = !c,
            additionalElement = a.document.createElement("button");
        additionalElement.setAttribute("onclick", $(this).parent().remove());
        b && (c = a.document.createElement("input"), c.setAttribute("type", "text"));
        c = {
            element: c,
            element2: additionalElement
        };
        b && a.insertHtml("<span>");
        b && a.insertElement(c.element);
        b && a.insertElement(c.element2);
        b && a.insertHtml("</span>");
        this.commitContent(c);
        b || a.getSelection().selectElement(c.element)
    }
```

I tried this approach, but the span-element does not appear in the source code of the page, when using it. I also tried using the div-element which breaks the p-element containing the whole input. (the p end at the div and a new starts after. 'div style="display: inline"' does not work either.) The at the moment most successfull approach, still not doing what i want, is using a 'a style="color: black; text-decoration: none"', which works as long as i dont double-click the textfield, if i double-click it, the link-dialog opens instead of the textfield-dialog.
I also tried adding an additional element:

```
var wrapper = a.document.createElement("span");
wrapper.append(c);
wrapper.append(additionalElement);
```

But i could not get the CKEditor to output it.

All help is appreciated, hopefully before i turn insane ;)

Comment: Your `setAttribute()` statement inside `onOK` function is syntactically wrong for 2 things -- (a) It has a semicolon(`;`) after the `remove()` (b) you do NOT need double quotes for `""$(this).parent().remove()""`, So finally that statement should look like  `additionalElement.setAttribute("onclick", $(this).parent().remove());`(without 2 double quotes).

Comment: That was just a copy&paste error, but thx anyway :) And this part works fine.

Comment: Ok then did you see any browser console errors ? Problems like this definitely will have errors popping on the browser console. Can you check

Comment: There appears to be no error in the console, and the source code looks like that `<p>
 Text before textfield&nbsp;
 <input type="text" data-cke-editable="1" contenteditable="false" value="textfield" autocomplete="off" style="width: 75px;">
 <button onclick="$(this).parent().remove()"></button>
</p>`

Comment: Does this source give you what you want .. If not can you tell me what change is expected ? Also check if the `onclick` value is whats expected

Comment: The button is there, and when i click it the whole text disappears, but i want only the textfield and the button to disappear.

Comment: Aww ok, is that it ? Then all you need to change is your onclick `onclick="$(this).parent().remove()"` to `onclick="$(this).prev().remove()"`. You are removing the parent of the `<button>` which is the whole text(`<p>`). You need to  only remove the previous element. `parent()` JQuery function removes the parent & not the previous element. JQuery `prev()` function does that. Hope this helped :-)

Comment: With this approach the button has also to be deleted. By modifying the solution for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258521/clear-icon-inside-input-text), exchanging the clear-command with the remove-command i have the desired functionality without the need of using a nested element.

Comment: Awesome, Glad you got it working then.