# How to add clear icon in input fields using materializecss

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm wondering if someone knows how to add clear button inside a text input using materializecss. (clear button will show once a value is inserted). I've tried from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258521/clear-icon-inside-input-text?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), but it won't work. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you'll have to implement that, not very complicated, you add an `eventListener` for when input's value changes , the event is called `input` and whenever the value changes you see if it's not empty you display the button, otherwise you hide it

and another `eventListener` on the button to set the value to empty and hide itself when it's clicked,

`materializecss` is primarily for styling , and it's up to you to put the button inside the input with margins or positioning

```js
const button = document.getElementById('clear')
const myInput = document.getElementById('myInput')

myInput.addEventListener('input', function(){
    if(this.value != "") button.style.opacity = 1
    else button.style.opacity = 0
});

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    myInput.value = "";
    this.style.opacity = 0
});
```

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#myInput{
    padding: 0 5px;
    
}
#clear{
    opacity: 0;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: -55px;
    transition: opacity 0.2s linear
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row" >
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" class="validate">
    <label for="email">myInput</label>
    <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" id="clear">Clear</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I've created an extension to `materializecss` so we do not have to add listeners to every document you wish to use the clearable input field on.

```js
/* 
Add this extension to the bottom of the unminified material.js file & re-minify for use in production.

 - Or - 

Add to a .js file after materialize has loaded.

*/

(function ($) {
  "use strict";

  var _defaults = {};

  /**
     * @class
     *
     */

  var ClearableInputField = (function (_Component22) {
    _inherits(ClearableInputField, _Component22);

    /**
       * Construct Tooltip instance
       * @constructor
       * @param {Element} el
       * @param {Object} options
       */
    function ClearableInputField(el, options) {
      _classCallCheck(this, ClearableInputField);

      var _this_custom1 = _possibleConstructorReturn(this, (ClearableInputField.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(ClearableInputField)).call(this, ClearableInputField, el, options));

      _this_custom1.el.M_ClearableInputField = _this_custom1;
      _this_custom1.options = $.extend({}, ClearableInputField.defaults, options);

      _this_custom1._setupEventHandlers();
      return _this_custom1;
    }

    _createClass(
      ClearableInputField,
      [
        {
          key: "destroy",

          /**
             * Teardown component
             */
          value: function destroy() {
            this._removeEventHandlers();
            this.el.M_ClearableInputField = undefined; 
          },
        }, 
        {
          key: "_setupEventHandlers",
          value: function _setupEventHandlers() {
            this._handleValueChangeBound = this._handleValueChange.bind(this);
            this._handleInputClickBound = this._handleInputClick.bind(this);
            var closeIcon = this.$el.siblings("i");

            this.el.addEventListener("change", this._handleValueChangeBound);
            this.el.addEventListener("keyup", this._handleValueChangeBound);

            if (closeIcon.length) closeIcon[0].addEventListener("click", this._handleInputClickBound);
          },
        },
        {
          key: "_removeEventHandlers",
          value: function _removeEventHandlers() {
            var closeIcon = this.$el.siblings("i");

            this.el.removeEventListener("change", this._handleValueChangeBound);
            this.el.removeEventListener("keyup", this._handleValueChangeBound);

            if (closeIcon.length) closeIcon[0].removeEventListener("click", this._handleInputClickBound);
          },
        },
        {
          key: "_handleValueChange",
          value: function _handleValueChange() {
            if (this.$el.val() == "" || this.$el.val() == null) {
              // this.$el.trigger("blur");
              // this.$el.siblings("label").removeClass("active");
              this.$el.siblings("i").css("opacity", 0);
            } else {
              this.$el.siblings("i").css("opacity", 1);
            }
          },

          /**
             * Handle Range Mousedown and Touchstart
             * @param {Event} e
             */
        },
        {
          key: "_handleInputClick",
          value: function _handleInputClick() {
            this.$el.val("");
            this.$el.trigger("blur");
            this.$el.siblings("label").removeClass("active");
            this.$el.siblings("i").css("opacity", 0);
          },

          /**
             * Handle Range Mousedown and Touchstart
             * @param {Event} e
             */
        },
      ],
      [
        {
          key: "init",
          value: function init(els, options) {
            return _get(ClearableInputField.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(ClearableInputField), "init", this).call(this, this, els, options);
          },

          /**
             * Get Instance
             */
        },
        {
          key: "getInstance",
          value: function getInstance(el) {
            var domElem = !!el.jquery ? el[0] : el;
            return domElem.M_ClearableInputField;
          },
        },
        {
          key: "defaults",
          get: function () {
            return _defaults;
          },
        },
      ]
    );

    return ClearableInputField;
  })(Component);

  M.ClearableInputField = ClearableInputField;

  if (M.jQueryLoaded) {
    M.initializeJqueryWrapper(ClearableInputField, "clearableInputField", "M_ClearableInputField");
  }
})(cash);

// call new function clearableInputField to initialize. 
$(".clearable-input-field input").clearableInputField();
```

```css
.input-field.clearable-input-field >.clearBtn {
    opacity: 0;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: -40px;
    transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
    user-select:none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-icons/3.0.2/iconfont/material-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<!-- 
  Add new <i> tag with the class "clearBtn" to input-field group
-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-content"> 
      <span class="card-title">
        Clearable Input Fields
      </span>
      <div class="row">
        <form class="col s12">
          <div class="row ">
            <div class="input-field clearable-input-field col s6">
              <input id="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
              <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
              <i class="material-icons red-text clearBtn">clear</i>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field clearable-input-field col s6">
              <input id="last_name" type="text" class="validate">
              <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
              <i class="material-icons red-text clearBtn">backspace</i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field clearable-input-field col s12">
              <input id="password" type="password" class="validate">
              <label for="password">Password</label>
              <i class="material-icons red-text clearBtn">delete</i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field clearable-input-field col s12">
              <input id="email" type="email" class="validate">
              <label for="email">Email</label>
              <i class="material-icons red-text clearBtn">sentiment_dissatisfied</i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```