# how to show clear X button in chrome with type Password

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to show clear X button in chrome with type Password
I am trying

```css
input[type="password"] {
  -webkit-appearance: searchfield;
}

input[type="password"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  -webkit-appearance: searchfield-cancel-button;
}
```

```html
<input type="password" placeholder="enter text here..." />
```

Comment: Do you need only native/pure css?

Comment: Dupe of this? I cannot test the password field myself https://stackoverflow.com/q/6258521/295783

Answer (score 3):

If you want native/pure CSS. This should work only in **Chrome**.

```css
.password {
  -webkit-text-security: disc;
}
```

```html
<input type="search" class="password" placeholder="enter text here..." />
```

Comment: It seems OP want pure css and I think your solution is pure, so what? you should say *If you want to pure CSS*

Comment: Thanks @Pedram... I was meaning 'if you don't want custom css'

Comment: @RitwickDey still not getting Clear X button

Answer (score 1):

For `input[type='password']` X icon is not supported. You have to manually take care of icon and click event or you can try with this

```css
.close-icon {
  border: 0 solid transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.close-icon:after {
  content: "X";
  display: block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 35px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.search-box:not(:valid)~.close-icon {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="password" name="focus" required class="search-box" placeholder="Enter search term" />
  <button class="close-icon" type="reset"></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this code.

```js
/**
 * Clearable text inputs
 */
$(".clearable").each(function() {
  
  var $inp = $(this).find("input:password"),
      $cle = $(this).find(".clearable__clear");

  $inp.on("input", function(){
    $cle.toggle(!!this.value);
  });
  
  $cle.on("touchstart click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $inp.val("").trigger("input");
  });
  
});
```

```css
/* Clearable text inputs */
.clearable{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.clearable input[type=password]{
  padding-right: 24px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.clearable__clear{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right:0; top:0;
  padding: 0 8px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.clearable input::-ms-clear {  /* Remove IE default X */
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="clearable">
  <input type="password" name="" value="" placeholder="">
  <i class="clearable__clear">&times;</i>
</span>
```