# How to position an x in an input widget to clear the content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap

With twitter bootstrap it is quite straight forward to create a Search style input widget:

[image]

Also the x is doable with Twitter bootstrap, but positioning the x in that spot, requires some CSS finetuning.

I managed to get the x in that position, but it isn't very reliable. With a responsive-design and different resolutions the x gets completely displaced.

```
.filter-close {
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    left: 5em;
    top: 1.25em;
    z-index: 3;
}

<form action="." method="get" class="form-search">
 <a class="close filter-close" href="#">x</a>                                           
    <div class="input-append">                  
        {{filter_form.last_name}}<button type="submit" class="btn"><i class='icon-filter'> </i></button>                </div>                          
</form>
```

Before trying to reinvent the wheel, is there any existing javascript library that could turn an input in an input-with-an-x-button? Something like Chosen.js for this purpose?
Or any advice how I could do this in a better way?

Many Thanks,

Comment: have you tried using pixels, rather than EMs? That might make its position more reliable

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I will try this and let you know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763258/is-there-something-ready-for-a-clear-button-on-search-textbox)

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7fRB/1/) basically does what you are looking to do.

You are headed in the right direction.

Comment: I streamlined @karthikr CSS a bit with a [revised fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7fRB/563/) .

Answer (score 1):

With some changes to some of the bootstrap code and a little JavaScript you can accomplish this, in fact you can place any control you want inside the textbox. Here is an example:

[image]

And here is the final markup used to generate it:

```
<div class="composite-input">
    <span class="focus-input">Filter:</span> 
    <input type="text" /> 
    <span>×</span>
</div>
```

For the full code check out this post: http://www.simplygoodcode.com/2013/08/placing-text-and-controls-inside-text.html

Answer (score 1):

Basically the key is to use `relative` positioning and `left:-20px` on the clearing element.

For example:

```
<input type="text" /><span id="userclear">x</span>

span#userclear
{
  position: relative;
  left: -20px;
}
```

This way the span will overlap the input to the left of it.  You can attach an event handler to it to clear the input field.